# Remove element from the array

Tags: c++

I want to be able to remove an item from the inventory that the use inputs ie remove helmet then it remove helmet from the array. I had an example but I couldnt figure out which one of my variables went where

```
void remData(const InventoryRecord list[], int size) {
    system("cls");
    cout <<"Enter Item you wish to remove from your inventory: " << endl;// This is being displayed so user can see items in the inventory
    double cost = 0;

  if(size < 1) {
    cout << "Nothing to display" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "All Items in your Bag" << endl << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);   
    cout << "Item Name              Qty     Value" << endl;// It is not displaying right the alignment is off
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
    /* from here I do not know what to do! What I want is have use type the item name they want removed
                            also display an error if they enter an  item wrong*/
    cout << left;     
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      cout << setw(21) << list[i].name << right
           << setw(4)  << list[i].qty
           << setw(10) << list[i].value << left << endl;
           cost = cost + list[i].value * list[i].qty;


    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
    cout << right << setw(3) << size;
    cout << " items listed";
    cout << right << setw(19) << cost << endl << endl;



    }}}
```

Comment: Too much code. [Please reduce it to the strict required minimum](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You can't remove an element from the array. You should use containers, say [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: If you actually want to remove an element from an array, you must move at least one element to close the gap (unless it's the last one). Or you could just mark that element as defunct. I for one will not take another look until you reduce the code as @한국매미 says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work but I would recommend using std::list since remove can be done in constant time. Remove on arrays can only be done in linear time if you want to preserve order (like I have). The other option is to just swap the empty place with the element at the size-1 position in the array and then subtract 1 from size.

Note: You have to change your function header, list[] can't be const if you want to modify it and since you're removing elements size should be pass-by-reference so it can be changed.

```
void remData(InventoryRecord list[], int &size) {
    system("cls");
    cout <<"Enter Item you wish to remove from your inventory: " << endl;// This is being displayed so user can see items in the inventory

    // the name we query for
    string qname;
    bool found = false;
    int index;

    if(size < 1) {
        cout << "Nothing to display" << endl;
    } else {
        // display the inventory for reference
        dispData(list, size);

        // prompt for name
        cout << "Name      : ";
        getline(cin, qname);
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            if ( qname == list[i].name )
            {
                found = true;
                index = i;
                // assuming only removing first item with this name
                break;
            }

        if (!found) {
            // you could re-prompt using a loop instead of just ending here
            cout << "Could not find item " << qname << "!" << endl;
        } else {
            // remove item from list and shift other items over the one we want to remove
            for ( int i = index; i < size-1; ++i )
            {
                // modifying list (this is why it can't be const)
                list[i].name = list[i+1].name;
                list[i].qty = list[i+1].qty;
                list[i].value = list[i+1].value;
            }
            // decrement the size (this is why it was pass-by-reference)
            size--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl remData(struct InventoryRecord const * const,int)" (?remData@@YAXQBUInventoryRecord@@H@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\Ashley\Documents\Visual Studio                      2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj ConsoleApplication2                                                                               .

Comment: Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals c:\Users\Ashley\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe ConsoleApplication2

Comment: These are the errors I get

Comment: I found my issue thank you